# Why would my app keep opened too many sleeping connections?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, azure-webjobs, ef-core-2.1

I have a .net core app which is deployed as a Webjob on Azure. It listens to a topic and according to what it reads it performs CRUD operations on a SQL Server Database (the App uses EF core for that).

The thing is that, as the application runs, the number of opened connections increases and most of them are not used for a long time (even for days).

is there a way to make the app not to create too many sleeping connections?

I have tried to run my app locally, using a local SQL Server DB (Express).  When I ran it, it only kept opened about 3 connections (with the same amount of message handled as when it is deployed as a webjob).

Comment: Do you close and dispose of the connections in your code? Either explicitly or with a USING statement.

Comment: @SeanLange yes. I use a using statement when I get an instance of my DbContext.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: using (var dbcontext = new MyDbContext())
                {
                    var personfromdb = dbcontext.Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == personfrommessage.Id);
                    if (personfromdb == null)
                    {                       
                        dbcontext.Persons.Add(person);
                        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

Comment: have you had the chance to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to make the app not to create too many sleeping connections?

Yes.  Likely the current behavior is fine, and it isn't creating *too many* sleeping connections.  But if you want to change the connection pooling behavior, you can:

> The [ConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8) property of the SqlConnection object supports
>   connection string key/value pairs that can be used to adjust the
>   behavior of the connection pooling logic. For more information, see
>   ConnectionString.

[SQL Server Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)

Comment: I have tried to do that and, apparently, it kept opened only at maximum the number of connection specified as Max Pool Size on the connectionstring.

On the other side, as time passes there are not used connections that remains opened for a long time not being used, and from the 10 opened connections, only 3 are actively used.

This does not happen when I run the application locally on my computer or in a docker container.